# Why do we have to use @Cacheable as well as @Cache in Hibernate for second-level of cache?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching, ehcache

I want to know why we have to use 2 annotations to use the second-level of cache in Hibernate.

We declare :

```
@Cacheable
@Cache
```

Why don't we declare directly `@Cache` with the options?

Comment: I believe `@Cacheable` is a Spring annotation to cache any set of data whether originated from database or not.

Comment: Can you give more context? Which documentation/example tells you that you have to use both annotations? Can you please also give a minimal code sample and not just the two annotations? Which version of Hibernate and JPA are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know why we have to use 2 annotations to use the
> second-level of cache in Hibernate.

You don't need to use both, but you can. To enable the second level cache on an entity, you have 2 options: 
(1) Use @Cacheable (more below)
(2) Use @Cache(more below)

[@Cacheable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-mappings) is the JPA cache interface(used on an entity) that together with `shared cache mode` property decides whether an entity will be cached or not.

> By default, entities are not part of the second level cache and we
> recommend you to stick to this setting. However, you can override this
> by setting the shared-cache-mode element in your persistence.xml file
> or by using the jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode property in your
> configuration file. The following values are possible:
>
> ENABLE_SELECTIVE (Default and recommended value) Entities are not
> cached unless explicitly marked as cacheable (with the @Cacheable
> annotation).
>
> DISABLE_SELECTIVE Entities are cached unless explicitly marked as
> non-cacheable.
>
> ALL Entities are always cached even if marked as non-cacheable.
>
> NONE No entity is cached even if marked as cacheable. This option can
> make sense to disable second-level cache altogether.

As per [this](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache):
Some developers consider that it is a good convention to add the
standard @javax.persistence.Cacheable annotation as well (**although not
required by Hibernate**).

[@Cache](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-mappings) is the Hibernate cache interface, **recommended** to specify the CacheConcurrencyStrategy on a per entity basis instead of the global setting `hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strategy`.

> Why don't we declare directly @Cache with the options ?

That's exactly what is recommended, so that besides telling Hibernate that you want to enable second level caching for this entity, you also keep the concurrency strategy on a per entity basis, instead of global, as explained above. Remember to enable the second level cache(as by default, it' not), by using `hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache`. A basic configuration of second level cache(I am using Spring Boot):

```
//In build.gradle:
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache' //IMPORTANT: If you are specifying a version, make sure that it is the same version as your Hibernate version that you are using.

//Hibernate properties(can also be externalized to application.properties):
properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true"); //hibernate.cache.use_second_level will also work
properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"); //act as a bridge between Hibernate and the caching provider

emf.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

//In the entity class:
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
```

**Note 1**: The above is using Ehcache 2.x
**Note 2**: To use Ehcache 3.x, use the following properties:

```
properties.put("hibernate.javax.cache.provider", "org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider");
properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "jcache");
```

**Note 3**: Collections are not cached by default, you need to explicitly mark them with `@Cache`.

**BONUS:**
If you want to check the statistics:

```
//Add this property:
properties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");

//And somewhere in your code:
sessionFactory.getStatistics();
```

Comment: That's interesting because the Hibernate docs explicitly state under https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-mappings for ENABLE_SELECTIVE (Default and recommended value):
"Entities are not cached unless explicitly marked as cacheable (with the @Cacheable annotation)."

Comment: Hello Dave, thanks for the comment and the link, that's right. I have expounded on my answer :). Feel free to edit. Cheers mate.

Comment: You still have a bolded "although not required by Hibernate" in there. I think that *could* be true if Hibernate is configured away from the default of ENABLE_SELECTIVE but in Hibernate's default configuration the docs imply that it *is* required by Hibernate. Thoughts?

Comment: Right, when i read it, it does imply that, you are right. But you don't actually need to use it if you use `@Cache`. I am not using `@Cacheable` at all in my applications, and so far the second level cache is working like a charm. No unnecessary trips to the database for data that never change.