# Is Hibernate 6 not compatible with Ehcache 3 for Spring Boot 3?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, ehcache-3

In a Spring Boot 3 application I have the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>${ehcache3.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, in the application.yml the following properties are set:

```yaml
spring.jpa.properties:
  -hibernate.generate_statistics: true
  -hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
  -hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: "jcache"
  -hibernate.javax.cache.provider: "org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider"
```

And at last, `@EnableCaching` is applied to a config class. But all the configuration above doesn't seem to work, since Hibernate still makes a database trip for each request for the following entity:

```java
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "email_status")
public class EmailStatus implements Serializable {

  //...
}
```

The query and statistics output is always the same:

```
    select
        e1_0.email_status_id,
        e1_0.description 
    from
        email_status e1_0 
    where
        e1_0.description=?
21:45:12 TRACE - [nio-8087-exec-2] o.h.o.j.bind                                      :  binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [PENDING]

...

21:45:12 INFO  - [nio-8087-exec-2] o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener    :  Session Metrics {
    12566 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    42664 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    73055 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    301863 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    87958 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

If I don't use any Hibernate specific settings and just let `spring-boot-starter-cache` do its work, annotating the entity with `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable` caching works - maybe not quite so performant, but at least is works.

Hibernate's [documentation here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-provider-jcache) tells in the infobox that compatible JCache implementations can be found [on the JPC website](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/implementations/jsr107/index.html). The link to the supported Ehcache implementation brings you to this **10 year old** [Ehcache 2.x version](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache-jcache). That can't be serious, or though?

Why can't I find any actual documentation of how to configure Hibernate 6 with Ehcache 3 for a Spring Boot 3 application? Is it possible, that this is a non working combination? All I find are outdated documentations or fiddeling examples without any context. However, after spending a few hours trying to get the thing working, I'm giving up. Either this isn't possible at all, or I'm just too dumb.

If anybody knows how to set up a proper Ehcache 3 for Hibernate 6 in Spring Boot 3, that would really be wonderful. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this instead of `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable`

```
@jakarta.persistence.Cacheable
```

Here is the minimum configuration you need to add. Besides `spring-data-jpa`, there are few dependencies required.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Also you need to add these configuration to `application.properties` to enable 2nd level cache.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=jcache
spring.jpa.hibernate.javax.cache.provider=org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider
```

On the entity class level, use this to enable cache

```
@jakarta.persistence.Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache
public class EmailStatus {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @phuongnq1995. Unfortunately, changing the annotation to ´@jakarta.persistence.Cacheable` doesn't work either, still not hitting the cache. Also the `@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache` annotation requires the usage attribute. Can you confirm, that your implementation is working?

Comment: Do you have an extra `ehcache.xml` config file in place? At the moment I don't have one, and during start up Hibernate moans about a missing cache but creates then one on-the-fly. However, it also says `created cache will use a  provider-specific default configuration: make sure you defined one`. Is such a configuration mandatory? I haven't read anything about this in any tutorials. And currently, the config files I can find don't seem to be compatible with this setup. I'd rather have the thing running first on a simple basis before starting to configure it properly.

Comment: Yeah it's work properly from my and I dont have any `ehcache.xml` file

Comment: Refer to 2nd cache level of this [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#second-level-cache) also you can see Hibernate create cache `EmailStatus` om startup automatically. Also refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010903/why-do-we-have-to-use-cacheable-as-well-as-cache-in-hibernate-for-second-level) to know why we need those 2 `@Cache` and `@Cacheable` of Jakarta

Comment: Yes, you're right. Your given solution works fine, and additionally I had an extra issue which I dragged from formerly using the Spring Boot built-in caching system, where query caching is somehow interwoven to the whole project, thus adding the `@Cacheable()` annotation to a method inside a service layer works fine. Unfortunately, with Hibernate you can't do this, but have to put the `@QueryHints()` annotation inside the repository. In the end, now it works as expected and I am really happy for today. Many many thanks for your help.